# Enlarge the stack frame - Alignment?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, x86-64, abi

Is it possible to enlarge the stack frame like this:

```
subq $1, %rsp
```

if we just want to store a `char` on the stack (for example).
Or do we need to enlarge the stack by a multiple of 8 or something. Is there any alignment?

Comment: Technically yes, but don't do it. Calling conventions mandate at least 8 bytes of alignment, possibly 16, if you intend to interoperate with other code. Also misalignment involves some performance penalties.

Comment: It is possible, x86 isn't very picky about it.  Don't make any function calls, the misaligned stack slows them down.  Or make them fail completely when they contain SIMD code, increasingly common  Since you shouldn't make calls, there is no point whatsoever in not adjusting the stack pointer by 4 or 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, "Yes."  You can enlarge the stack frame precisely in the way that you have indicated.  However, as you ask in the rest of your question, you may run into stack alignment issues.

These issues will rarely cause problems within your own code.  Honestly, you can manage the stack and pass parameters in any way that you'd like as long as you're not violating some architectural limitation.

However, to interoperate with system and library calls, stack alignment will generally be a requirement.  You might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) document useful.  Just as one example, GCC under Linux on x86 and x86_64 expects (enforces) 16 byte alignment of the stack and uses `cdecl`.

You would want to locate any calling standard and alignment requirements in the reference documents for the platform and libraries that you're working with.

Comment: You mean `cdecl` not `stdcall`.

Comment: Hmm.. Whoops!  Thanks!

Comment: @jester someday I need to get you into a chat and find out your background.  Your assembly knowledge is truly broad and impressive. :)